# Pinch to zoom gesture working perfectly on ipad2 but not on retina iPad?

Tags: uiscrollview, pinchzoom

The title of the question speaks itself. For more assistance I would like to tell that my app has been developed using the Apple Photo Scroller(A modification of Apple's PhotoScroller sample code to load the UIPageViewController inside a UIViewController subclass
), with multiple image galleries. The problem is the pinch-to-zoom functions perfectly on ipad2 but not on retina iPads. My images are of size 2048x1536.

Can anybody tell me why the zoom is not working on retina iPads?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking that the `contentScaleFactor` is set to 1.

From PhotoScroller's TilingView.m file:

```
// to handle the interaction between CATiledLayer and high resolution screens, we need to
// always keep the tiling view's contentScaleFactor at 1.0. UIKit will try to set it back
// to 2.0 on retina displays, which is the right call in most cases, but since we're backed
// by a CATiledLayer it will actually cause us to load the wrong sized tiles.
//
- (void)setContentScaleFactor:(CGFloat)contentScaleFactor
{
    [super setContentScaleFactor:1.f];
}
```

See these related questions and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665853/rendering-content-after-zoomed-in-for-uiscrollview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272633/what-is-the-secret-behind-contentscalefactor-of-uiview-when-used-with-catiledl) for more info on `contentScaleFactor`.